# gtest_ assigning value in a function by using setargpointee

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I am testing on a adapter function with gtest and cannot successfully use SetArgPointee in my test.

```
class Adapter:{
    public:
    int getTaskStateAdapter(){
       //do something
       int task_state = -1;
       int exit_value = -1;
       result = getTaskState(&task_state, &exit_value);

       if(result != 0){
          //throws here
       }
       if(exit_value != 0){
          //throws here
       }

    return task_state; 
    }
}
```

What I am testing is to check if the adapter function will throw an exception if the exit_value is not 0.

```
TEST(class_name, test_name){
    EXPECT_CALL(ClassMock::instance(), getTaskState(_,_)).WillOnce(DoAll(SetArgPointee<1>(-1), Return(0)));//Mock class is included in the test file

    EXPECT_THROW(Adapter::getTaskAdapter(), ERxEXC::Exception);//ERxEXC::Exception is a self-defined exception
}
```

However, whatever value I set in the SetArgPointee to the exit_value, the exception has never been thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These test codes are completely correct, the problem comes from the source code.